# Date new API support - Swift 4.0.3

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I am stuck with `DateTimeHelper` class which I installed from the [ZamZamKit Framework](https://github.com/ZamzamInc/ZamzamKit) framework Cocoapod.

I tried already using the fix-helper (Xcode 9) to some of the code in frameworks. I am working on this:

```
public func incrementDay(date: Date = Date(), numberOfDays: Int = 1) -> Date {
    Calendar.current.component(byAdding: .Day, value: numberOfDays, from: date, options: [])!
```

The problem is on the `addingByUnit` method which outputs error:

> Extra argument 'value' in call

Comment: That's because that method doesn't seem to exist either in [Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar) or in [the library you posted](https://github.com/ZamzamInc/ZamzamKit/blob/master/Sources/Extensions/Calendar.swift). Where did you get this code from?

Comment: U mean the method provided by ZamZamKit? I embedded the framework from Cocoapod which extract the DateTimeHelper.swift file. When i try to build, this new Xcode 9 outputs build time error. I know from the repo itself we could not find following method and that leaves me wonder. @Dima

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4, there are some change in method to get next date by adding component as following.

```
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.day, value: 1, to: Date())
```

This code will give you next date of arguments date passed in "to" parameter. Before swift 4 there are "from" parameter. Apple is going to more forward and precise things.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the help! It works now! Nice one!

Comment: @megatcorloene If this is helpful then accept as answer, so its needful to other people also.